# Error sending MTOM request to WSO2 ESB

Tags: wso2, esb, mtom

I'm using wso2 ESB in order to mediate request from a client to a web service, but I can't send MTOM attachments. ESB replies with error "Mime parts not found".
The sample MTOMSwASampleService give me same error too.
Can anyone help me? How can I send MTOM attachments through ESB?

Comment: Can you share the code you have on the ESB. And tell us how you are sending the request?

Answer (score 0):

Try preserving `Content-type` header and see.

Add the following property to `repository/conf/passthru-http.properties` file.

```
http.headers.preserve=Content-Type
```